# Avoid L suffix for Long in python

Tags: python, long-integer, python-2.x, string-conversion

I have a dictionary which may have long values for some key. I want to convert this dictionary to string and send it to a server. But when I am converting it to a string using str(dict) function for the values which have a long value is suffixed with 'L'. This when I am sending it to a server the value it is generating a problem. So can anyone suggest me a easier way of  what I can do to avoid the 'L' suffix

Comment: I added the Python 2.x tag as this problem doesn't exist in Python 3. Consider upgrading if you don't have dependencies that prevent you from doing so.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your use case is but to solve this problem and quite possibly the next problem you'll have I'd suggest using json.

```
import json
a = {'a': 10, 'b': 1234567812345678L}
print json.dumps(a)

# output:
{"a": 10, "b": 1234567812345678}
```

Comment: I can do what you are suggesting but problem is it will convert all the ' to " when we are printing. I have to send this string to a server where they do string parsing and it will be expecting ', hence gives an error. I cant do replace all " to ' because some values might contain " in the values. Is there any other method?

Comment: In most situations you can help"the other side" by suggesting that they also use a standard like json. I know that you can't always control the other side so if you have a narrower use case then you can use `json.dumps(a).replace('"',"'")`

Answer (score 1):

This is because calling `str` on the dict will still call `repr` to get the representation of it's contents.

You should just write your own function to iterate over the dict

```
>>> D = {10000000000000000+n:n for n in range(10)}
>>> print D
{10000000000000000L: 0, 10000000000000001L: 1, 10000000000000002L: 2, 10000000000000003L: 3, 10000000000000004L: 4, 10000000000000005L: 5, 10000000000000006L: 6, 10000000000000007L: 7, 10000000000000008L: 8, 10000000000000009L: 9}
>>> print "{{{}}}".format(', '.join("{}: {}".format(*i) for i in D.items()))
{10000000000000000: 0, 10000000000000001: 1, 10000000000000002: 2, 10000000000000003: 3, 10000000000000004: 4, 10000000000000005: 5, 10000000000000006: 6, 10000000000000007: 7, 10000000000000008: 8, 10000000000000009: 9}
```

Comment: I am new to python Can you explain me what you did in  
"{{{}}}".format(', '.join("{}: {}".format(*i) for i in D.items())) statement
and the long integer are in values section not keys section. How will I modify you function

Answer (score 0):

Unrolling gnibbler's code is close to this:

```
# put all key-value-pairs into a list, formatted as strings
tmp1 = []
for i in D.items()
    tmp2 = "{}: {}".format(*i)
    tmp1.append(tmp2)

# create a single string by joining the elements with a comma
tmp3 = ", ".join(tmp1)

# add curly braces
tmp4 = "{{{}}}".format(tmp3)

# output result
print tmp4
```

The inner part of his construction is called a generator expression. They are a bit more efficient, because they don't require the temporary list (or tuple) "tmp1" and allow very terse syntax. Further, they can make code almost unreadable for people not familiar with the construct, if you have that problem try reading it from the inside out. ;^)